# Using Razor Templates to produce a .aspx page

Tags: c#, razor, tridion

I am trying to use a Razor template to produce a .aspx page as output. I'm not having luck looking in the documentation for how to do this. The Page and namespace declarations are breaking the template:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Title="@Page.Metadata.browser_title" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml" %>
```

These are causing this error:

TemplateCompileException: CS1501: No overload for method 'Write' takes 0 arguments Line 27 Column 1: Write();

I assume this is because Razor templates using C# syntax makes the two conflict, since the declarations above use "@". Is there a way to get them to work together so a Razor template can produce an output with C# in the rendered product after the template is run? The example above also shows how the value for "Title" needs to be rendered out of the template.

Comment: Why on earth are you doing that?

Comment: Since the Razor Mediator for Tridion creator doesn't seem to hang out in SO, I'd recommend asking him on his blog: http://www.codedweapon.com/

Comment: It is first going through a content management system called Tridion, where the content on the page is entered by non-developers. I've been using DWT previously but I am working on a proof of concept for using Razor instead for more flexible options in the layout template. Razor/C# operates the template code, but the pages on the production servers have C# on them as well as well because the site is .net based and uses masterpages, user controls, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `@`s in the `<%` are invalid Razor syntax.
You need to escape them by writing `<%@@`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the trick! I had tried @<%@ and @{<%@ ... } while guessing at the syntax to resolve it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

If you like Razor, maybe you should check out DD4T (http://code.google.com/p/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/). It allows you to build a web site using ASP.Net MVC with Razor views.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a C# TBB to add the tags after all your Razormediator templates or even better if you could add after the Default Finish Actions(if you're using one).

Quick and dirty sample code...

```
  Item OutputItem = package.GetByName(Package.OutputName);
  string OutputText = OutputItem.GetAsString();

  // Page tag declaration..
  string pagePretags = @"<<TWO LINES OF DECLARATIONs..>>"
  string FinalOutputText = pagePretags + OutputText ;

  OutputItem.SetAsString(FinalOutputText);
```

Hope this helps..